# How to make fixed width of column with Helvetica font?

Tags: c++

Usually, I use iomanip and **setw** to make a column with a fixed width for output.
But it seems to be that it doesn't work with Helvetica font.
What to do with it here?

Comment: Helvetica is a proportional font (all glyphs do not have the same width). You cannot achieve fixed width with a proportional font.

Comment: Is there any good solution how to make two columns in output? Sometimes people use tabs, but it seems to me not nice...

Comment: Even tabs only (partially) work if the output device knows about tab stops. Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately), your standard output is not Microsoft Word.

Comment: Use a real fixed width font, such as Terminal.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your output target is? Are you displaying stuff in a console? In a GUI (if so, which toolkit)? Are you outputting for a specific file format? The answer depends on these details. Better yet, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm displaying in GUI, using Fox Toolkit.

Comment: If you want to use `setw` change to a fixed-width font.  *Courier New* is a fixed width font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica is a proportional font which means that the letters have different widths.

BTW, for most GUIs, you'll need something more specialized than `std::cout`.

In order to make a fixed width column you will need to pad to get to the next column.  This means adding up the widths of the characters and the spacing.  Subtract this from the column width and this becomes your padding.

Many GUIs have functions for determining the pixel widths of a string of text.

An easier route, IMHO, is to use a grid type widget in your GUI.  These have column capabilities that can be adjusted.  Some have functions that will resize a column based on its contents.  You only need to put the text into that column.

Another GUI technique is to use vertical "boxes" (sizers) for each column.  Place your text into the box.  Let the box figure out its alignment and padding.

Comment: OK. I am using multiline text widget in Fox Toolkit - FXText.
Vertical boxers is seemed to be nice for me.
Is there such technique in FXText?